# Max flow visualization with JavaScript api - use d3.js, or something similar?

Tags: javascript, python, graph, visualization, network-flow

I'm looking to implement (or use a library if one already exists) the Max Flow algorithm on a graph with directed and undirected edges, and visualize it. I am leaning toward JavaScript. I am aware that d3.js and arbor.js allow interactive graph visualization, but is there a recommended way to visualize **the actual flow** from node to node? This is to demonstrate some concepts in theoretical computer science.

The ideal graph would be able to show **edge capacities, edge costs (different from capacities), and node names**, and edges can be **one-way** (directed) or **two-way** (bidirectional, arrows pointing to both nodes, or just no arrows at all. This is **not** two separate directed edges).

Any advice regarding a graph visualization tool - one where you can see the flow going from edge to edge - would be appreciated.

Note: I am not opposed to using Python or some other language if someone is aware of a nice framework/library that allows this kind of visualization.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

d3 may be the solution to what you're trying to do, but it's good to keep in mind what it is and what it is not.

What it is: a very effective tool at creating data-based graphics. What it is not: a graphing library. That being said, you CAN use it for graphs. Most of the graphs that I do in javascript are built on d3, but when doing so, expect to do write a lot of to code for setting up your plots. You can create a flow graph that will show you what you want, but d3 doesn't contain a canned flow graph that you can drop your data into.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [Sankey diagram in d3.js](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/) and go through [the intro in d3.js](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-kcP9b/0/1) to see how to deal with that.